# When running Node.js with Oracle DB, the connection pool takes too much time to be created

Tags: node.js, oracle, express, connection-pooling, node-oracledb

I have a Node.js application. It connects to Oracle DB using node-oracledb package.

When I run node js on our test environment, it's close to instant before receiving the message "Connection Pool created". On client's environment, it takes up to 10 or 20 seconds.

**Pool parameters:**

- Min pool 1
- Max pool 10
- Pool increment 1
- 4 clusters
- UV_THREADPOOLSIZE:128 (node limitation on the version we use 10.16)
- pool ping interval : 30

Rest is default

On the other hand, when running queries through SQL Navigator, it's also slow.

On the cmd i see:

- "Info Express Listening on port 3000"

Then after up to 20s:

- "Connection pool created"

In terms of hardware, both application server and DB server are way more powerfull than they should be so I don't think it can be the problem. And with less powerfull servers I don't have this problem in my environnment. Also, on the oracle db server, AV scanning is excluding db storage files and db executables and files.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Can you update your question and give information such as the pool parameters. Also it's better to cut & paste text instead of screenshots.

Comment: Thx Cristopher I updated the initial post based on your comments.

Comment: The start time is excessive only for one connection.  Can you check into the machine connectivity issues - is pinging between them fast?  Is DNS slow?  Is SQL*Plus (not SQL Navigator or SQL Developer) slow to connect and also to execute a query?  What do you have in your node.js sqlnet.ora file (if you have one)?  If this doesn't get you anywhere, then update your post with a full, runnable Node.js file that shows how you start the connection pool (and that also has the slow connection issue).